# OpenWRT: how to apply changes of uci system file

Tags: configuration, openwrt, timezone

I am using UCI command to set timezone:

```
uci set system.@system[0].zonename="America/Los_Angeles"
```

the change reflects immediately after I run:

```
uci commit
```

But the changes are not reflected on system time. And after reboot I see the changes that are committed in `/etc/config/system` file.

Is there any way I can apply changes without reboot?

I did not find `/etc/init.d/system` file as any other, to restart/start/stop and apply changes without reboot.

Also FYI, I don't have `/etc/config/timezone` file.

Answer (score 1):

The timezone you use, must be listed in `/etc/TZ`

1. make sure `/tmp/TZ` exists
2. check if `/etc/TZ` exists. If not, copy the `TZ` file from `/tmp` to `/etc`

I am quite confident, that `/etc/config/timezone` is not even needed.

Answer (score 0):

Luci have fatals bugs.
You need to manually commit unsaved changes.

```
nvram show // to verify the changes
nvram commit
```

Comment: Hello sir what bugs are you talking about? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

find your TZ string in Time Zones

[image]

```
$ cd /tmp
$ echo PST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0> TZ
```